# 502 error with nginx for a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm building an app using rails, unicorn and nginx on centos.  I'm very new to doing the server side of things but I'm trying to [follow this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5) and get an application running.

This is my nginx default.conf file:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.rqm3.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {


    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    root /www/rqm3/;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

here is my unicorn file:

```
# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory "/www/rqm3"

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "/www/rqm3/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "/www/rqm3/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/www/rqm3/log/unicorn.log"

# Unicorn socket
listen "/tmp/unicorn.[app name].sock"
listen "/tmp/unicorn.rqm3.sock"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

and here's my nginx error log

```
2015/08/06 14:37:44 [crit] 24375#0: *30 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.rqm3.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.2.213, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.rqm3.sock:/", host: "192.168.1.29:8080"
```

Comment: Silly question, but are you starting your rails (rack) app? Also, is the `listen "/tmp/unicorn.[app name].sock"` line in your unicorn file a typo?

Comment: The app is started,  and the line in question was directly copied from the tutorial, I'll try it without that line and see if it changes anything.

Comment: just added the error log, it seems like I don't have the correct permissions but I have it set to "775"

Answer (score 0):

On my Rails 5 + Puma + Nginx setup I only ever see `502` when doing [cross-origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) from `www.example.com` to `api.example.com`.

In case your browser is sending `OPTIONS` requests and your server returns `502` errors, it's a sign your server is cross-origin. Your browser will then first send a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request to see if it's safe to send sensitive data. That request should pass Nginx, pass Unicorn and hit Rack before it hits Rails. Rails sanitises your request. If your origin is permitted, Rack will return `200` to your browser after which the browser can then send the actual `GET`, `POST`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` requests you meant to send.

To open up your [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in [Rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) you can use this initializer:

```
# config/initializers/cors.rb
# https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'example.com'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```